# Angular execute the method first and then navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to execute a method which calls API so once the api is executed i want to navigate the URL.

Currently i have the already tried below code :

```
this._router
      .navigate(valuationRoute)
      .then(data => { 
        if (!data) {
          this.getContent();
        }
      })

private getContent = async () => {
    try {
      this.isLoaded = false;
      localStorage.ReportDataStart = new Date();
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.spinnerService.show();

      if (this._fundBusinessId && this._fundPeriod && this._templateTypeId) {
        this.reportDataService.getContent(`val/api/${this._dealCode}/${this._fundPeriod}/${this._fundBusinessId}/${parseInt(this._templateTypeId)}`
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.isLoaded = false;
      this.fireRefreshComments = true;
      this.isRefreshing = false;
      this.spinnerService.hide();
      const errorMessage = this._customMessageService.formatError(error);
      this._alertService.error(
        this._messageService.displayReportError
      );
    }
  }
```

i want to call `this.getcontent` and within `this.getcontent` an `api` is being called once i get the result from api i want to navigate. Please help

Comment: Show us getContent method!

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya i have added getcontent method

Answer (score 0):

Just add route navigation code after response from API like this :

```
this.reportDataService.getContent(//yourparams).then(() => {
    //put your navigation code here
    this.router.navigate(//routepath)
})
```

Comment: I already tried this i also added async and await but same issue. Actually my html is loaded and then i am changing the option in dropdown menu and then is when i am facing this problem